# ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django, django-settings, restframeworkmongoengine

I'm trying to make MongoDB and Django get on with each other the way I want them to.
That's the error I'm getting when trying to import viewsets from rest_framework_mongoengine.

The whole error looks like this:

`ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

It doesn't find `settings.py` or what? If so I can't figure out why! Namely, say, why did this problem not appear with other modules then?

Here are my `INSTALLED APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_mongoengine',
    'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'core',
    'core.essences.user',
    'core.essences.user.authentication',
    'core.essences.test_result',
]
```

Comment: You haven't shows us the code where you actually try to do this import.

Comment: oh my bad, I forgot to mention that I'm doing it in python's interactive mode.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Most common cause of this is that you're just running `python` instead of using `python manage.py shell`, which means you need to manually set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable so Django knows where to find your settings (`manage.py shell` does that for you automatically).

It's also possible (but less common) that you have something that's trying to import settings during the process of setting up your settings. To determine if that's the case, look at your settings file for any imports or function calls that might need to access settings (including code in things being imported by your settings file).

Answer (score 12):

For anyone still experiencing this issue with little resolve, Ensure the setdefault DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is moved to the top of the script file.

```
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_crazy_service.settings')
django.setup()

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
```

disregard the squiggly marks

Comment: Worked! But now I need to do this for every single pytest file, as it was my pytest files that were demanding to know where the settings.py is. Anyone know how to do this globally, without having to use the shell?

Answer (score 6):

Try this in your `xx.py:`

```
from yourProjectName.wsgi import *
```

Comment: I got this error when running django-channels with daphne. I imported all the wsgi details to my asgi file from your help, now it's working perfect thanks to you!

Comment: This solved my issue--thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Run `python manage.py shell` instead of running `python` to reach environment shell in your project. `Python` does not simply recognize `django` installed apps by default.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using windows run

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= <yourProjectName>.settings
```

(or) navigate to the folder containing settings file in terminal and run

```
set  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
```

Comment: In the shell, in config.py or in command line? Doing this in the shell produces a syntax error, so I have no idea where people should put this set.

Answer (score 1):

try `python manage.py shell` instead of `python` in terminal for interactive environment.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this exception in the python console in pycharm when I run the following command,

```
from app_name.models import model_name
```

by the soloution present above, before this command, I used below command and the problem is solved

```
from project_name.wsgi import *
```