# ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured - Scraper

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I try to run my scraper in Django I get the following error.

This happened when I tried to put the scraped data into the database using the built-in Django models.

traceback and error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/xxxxxx/Desktop/project/teo/movierater/scrap.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxxxx/Desktop/project/teo/movierater/scrap.py", line 7, in <module>
    from teo.movierater.api.models import *
  File "/home/xxxxxx/Desktop/project/teo/movierater/api/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Author(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 103, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 64, in _setup

    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I put it in *bin/activate:*

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

Here is the code snippet from scraper.py:

```
import django
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from teo.movierater.api.models import *


os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'movierater.settings'
django.setup()
```

When I try import models below django.setup():

```
import django
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'movierater.settings'
django.setup()

from teo.movierater.api.models import *
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'movierater'
```

My project structure and the settings:

[image]

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'movierater.api',
]
```

wsgi.py file:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'movierater.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: what server you're using?

Comment: import models after ```django.setup()```

Comment: @waynetech I did it and now i get - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'movierater'

Comment: @RamyMohamed I just use elephantsql.com

Comment: after ```django.setup()``` then ```from api.models import *```?

Comment: Look at the editions. 
I described it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of possible issues here.

1. use `movierater.settings` as `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` value, i.e. `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=movierater.settings`

   - please note that `movierater`'s location must be on your `PYTHONPATH` ([ImproperlyConfigured: You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set))
2. how do you start your app, did you try `python manage.py shell`?

   - [ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074690/improperlyconfigured-requested-setting-installed-apps-but-settings-are-not-con)
3. if you you want to start your scraper as a script (e.g. `python manage.py scraper`) then the best way to do it is to write a custom command; take a look at [use django: from "python manage.py shell" to python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847469/use-django-from-python-manage-py-shell-to-python-script)

Comment: where should I attach : export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=movierater.settings

Comment: It's an environment variable, run `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=movierater.settings` in your shell (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps)

Comment: This command
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=movierater.settings
is not valid. It produces a syntax error in the shell.